# How do I make top and bottom of a section curved inwards instead of outwards using html and css with an image in as the background?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a section which should be curved inwards on top and bottom, having an image in the background. I tried using svg and path but could not get the desired result.

I have inserted below a link of an image which is the result that I want.

```css
section {
    padding: 60px 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="statistics" data-dir="up" style="background-image: url(https://hero.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-attachment: fixed;" class="statistics-section text-white parallax">
        
<svg id="bigHalfCircleCandy" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="fill:#ffffff;padding:0;">
  <path d="M0 0 C55 180 100 0 100 0 Z"></path>
</svg>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343464/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same path and rotate it by 180 degrees, then absolutely position it on the bottom of the section. To make sure the elements heights fits I had to add an explicit heights on the `section` element.

```css
section {
    margin: 60px 0;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
#statistics {
  background: url(https://codropspz-tympanus.netdna-ssl.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/blend-mode-example-screenshot.png);
  background-size: cover; 
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
#bigHalfCircleCandyBottom {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="statistics" data-dir="up" class="statistics-section text-white parallax">
        
<svg id="bigHalfCircleCandy" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="fill:#ffffff;padding:0;">
  <path d="M0 0 C55 180 100 0 100 0 Z"></path>
</svg>

<svg id="bigHalfCircleCandyBottom" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="fill:#ffffff;padding:0;">
  <path d="M0 0 C55 180 100 0 100 0 Z"></path>
</svg>
</section>
```

A more complete example along with a container for the text in the middle can be found in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/s6tawfxn/16/).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it.

```css
:root, html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), center / cover no-repeat url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSGvXdNxVmnn-fpjDeYYX-BqwD4mzPn6D79pw&usqp=CAU");
}

#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
  background: white;
  clip-path: ellipse(65% 80% at center -40%);
}

#center {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
  background: white;
  clip-path: ellipse(65% 80% at center 140%);
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="center">
    Some Interesting Facts About Us
  </div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```