# css clip-path partial circles

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I am trying to replicate this clipping in css and finding it impossible to get partial cricles and multiple instances of a clip path.

[image]

Basically I am wanting to get the curved bottom top edges (ignore the pink box).

I thought something like,

`clip-path: circle(50%, 50%)` but not that is clip path that runs too far down the element and is large of a circle.

I thought about maybe absolute `:before` & `:after` elements but that feels hacky?

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343464/8620333

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if you can do this with css `clip-path` property, but you can use `background-image` as svg vector. Make SVG with rounded sides, and `fill` property with that background image.

```
<svg width="502" height="162" viewBox="0 0 502 162" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<path d="M501.5 162V0.5C305.81 41.1562 196.035 41.1985 0.5 0.5V162C196.015 122.401 305.709 122.384 501.5 162Z" fill="url(yoururl.svg)"/>
</svg>
```

That svg looks like this:

```html
       <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 502 162" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <path d="M501.5 162V0.5C305.81 41.1562 196.035 41.1985 0.5 0.5V162C196.015 122.401 305.709 122.384 501.5 162Z" fill="green"/>
    </svg>
```

You can use this `<svg>`, copy this to new file, replace url attribute on `<path>` element, change style of the container to this:

```
background: url(yourfile.svg);
background-size: cover;
```